# Multiprocessing data loading in colab

Tags: python, dataset, optimization, colab

I want to convert mozilla common voice dataset from mp3 to wav. But this dataset is large and convertion takes many time. How can I make this convertion in colab with multiprocessing to decrease time of conversion?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **multiprocessing** library in Python to speed up the conversion of Mozilla Common Voice dataset from mp3 to wav in Colab.

Here's an example code snippet that you can use:

```py
import multiprocessing
import os
from pydub import AudioSegment

def convert_file(file_path):
  if file_path.endswith('.mp3'):
    sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3(file_path)
    new_file_path = file_path[:-3] + 'wav'
    sound.export(new_file_path, format='wav')
    os.remove(file_path)
    print(f"Converted {file_path} to {new_file_path}")
  else:
    print(f"Skipping {file_path}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
  # Set the path to your Mozilla Common Voice dataset folder
  data_dir = 'path/to/mozilla_common_voice_dataset'

  # Get a list of all mp3 files in the dataset folder
  mp3_files = [os.path.join(dirpath, f)
               for dirpath, _, filenames in os.walk(data_dir)
               for f in filenames if f.endswith('.mp3')]

  # Create a pool of worker processes
  num_processes = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
  pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=num_processes)

  # Map the conversion function to the list of mp3 files using the pool of worker processes
  pool.map(convert_file, mp3_files)

  # Close the pool of worker processes
  pool.close()
```

This code will use all available CPU cores in Colab to convert the mp3 files to wav format in **parallel**.